# Any alternatives to local storage for saving checkbox selections on page refresh

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Ok, I have about 50 webpages each page has a search form, each form has exactly to same checkboxes and dropdown options, is there any way to save the checkbox and dropdown selections on page refresh **without using local storage**?

The problem is using local storage works fine for say page 1 with retaining selections on page refresh, but because all search forms on all pages are the same when I go to say page 2, the same checkboxes and dropdowns remain selected, unless there is a way to clear the selections when moving to a new page.

Just wondering if there are any alternative options?

Comment: Try using cookies, hope it solves your problem.

Comment: How large are your forms? Storing the selection in the url might be an option, this could also give you a more concise way to clear selections, there are other advantages like sharing links and bookmarking.

Comment: There are cookies and IndexedDB techically. However, your problem doesn't seem related to *where* you're storing data but *how*. You should be able to differentiate the page 1 and page 2 forms in local storage, so you don't get the wrong data back from it. We can probably help addressing that concern if you share what your data looks like and how you're storing it.

Comment: Can you share an example of your data saved in localstorage ?